# Specifying base url for css

Tags: html, css, url, path

I had to split up a long css file. I put the smaller css files within a `styles` directory.

Now I have to update the the urls to go up one level with the `../` notation.

Is there anyway to specify the base URL from which to load assets like with the base tag in HTML, but with CSS?

Answer (score 65, accepted):

No, there isn't. I suggest to place the CSS images in at least the same level as the CSS file so that you don't need to go backwards in the path. E.g. `/css` folder for CSS files and `/css/images` folder for CSS images. Then you can consistently use `url('images/name.ext')` for CSS images. This way you can place the root `/css` folder practically everywhere without fiddling with the image URL's.

Answer (score -3):

An alternative way to set the base directory in the CSS (which seems to be impossible) is to set the base directory of the HTML document with the `<base>` tag. This tag is not well known in the community but I found a nice tutorial in the web:

https://webdesign.tutsplus.com/articles/quick-tip-set-relative-urls-with-the-base-tag--cms-21399

It seems to be totally a good solution.

Comment: Sorry, this doesn't work for links within CSS.