# set base-uri for css when using url()

Tags: css, travis-ci, github-pages, base-url

in my css I use url() at some places in this way:

```
style="background-image:url(/images/home/abschnitt1.jpeg)"
```

this approach generally works and it shows me the background image the way I want when I deploy the website. However for staging purposes I would like to deploy it to github pages aswell. The problem is that with github pages my websites base-uri is not the one I need.
It search the pictures at

```
https://<username>.github.io/
```

but the website is actually at

```
https://<username>.github.io/<repository name>
```

This means it never find these images. My current workaround is that since I deploy it with travis it just renames the stuff in the following way:

```
mv index.html index.html.old
sed "s/url(/url(\/website-staging1/g" index.html.old > index.html
```

While this works for this purpose thats definetly a super ugly solution. However I did not find a solution on how to do this without manually fixing the uri.
So my question is how I can do this without manually renaming it in this way, whether thats by some kind of a base uri or including it in a different way

Comment: Possible dup https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3812375/specifying-base-url-for-css

Comment: @arieljuod Well I do not see how this answers my question, because I have the problem that I do have really a different base url and do not just want to place my css in a different folder.

Comment: One hacky way I can think of, since the relative urls works relative to the CSS file, you could have 2 css files, one at /pubic and one at /public/repository-name (I guess one just a link to the other) and only change the url of the CSS link tag instead of changing the urls inside the file.

Comment: the answer to your actual question is that there's no way to set the base for urls inside CSS files other than where you place the file.

Comment: as I wrote I use github pages, so there is no option to place files lower than the git repositories root. I search for options to overcome this problem, because I guess I am not the first person using github pages with background images in the css